# WinError 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: python, imdbpy, windowserror

I am using a python script to fetch info from Imdb. While running it on Thorny, I am getting the following error:

```
2022-09-09 19:44:04,772 CRITICAL [imdbpy] C:\Users\Administrator.KRATER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\imdb\_exceptions.py:32: IMDbDataAccessError exception raised; args: ({'errcode': None, 'errmsg': 'None', 'url': 'https://www.imdb.com/find?q=titanic&s=tt', 'proxy': '', 'exception type': 'IOError', 'original exception': URLError(ConnectionRefusedError(10061, 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it', None, 10061, None))},); kwds: {}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.KRATER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1346, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.KRATER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1279, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.KRATER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1325, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.KRATER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1274, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.KRATER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1034, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.KRATER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 974, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.KRATER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1441, in connect
    super().connect()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.KRATER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 945, in connect
    self.sock = self._create_connection(
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.KRATER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\socket.py", line 844, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.KRATER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\socket.py", line 832, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.KRATER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\imdb\parser\http\__init__.py", line 220, in retrieve_unicode
    response = uopener.open(url)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.KRATER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 517, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.KRATER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 534, in _open
    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.KRATER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.KRATER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1389, in https_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.KRATER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1349, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.KRATER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1346, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.KRATER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1279, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.KRATER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1325, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.KRATER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1274, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.KRATER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1034, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.KRATER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 974, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.KRATER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1441, in connect
    super().connect()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.KRATER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 945, in connect
    self.sock = self._create_connection(
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.KRATER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\socket.py", line 844, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.KRATER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\socket.py", line 832, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.KRATER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\imdb\parser\http\__init__.py", line 220, in retrieve_unicode
    response = uopener.open(url)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.KRATER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 517, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.KRATER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 534, in _open
    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.KRATER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.KRATER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1389, in https_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.KRATER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1349, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.KRATER\Desktop\filmography -fetch.py", line 5, in <module>
    movie = ia.search_movie('titanic')
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.KRATER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\imdb\__init__.py", line 438, in search_movie
    res = self._search_movie(title, results)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.KRATER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\imdb\parser\http\__init__.py", line 407, in _search_movie
    cont = self._get_search_content('tt', title, results)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.KRATER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\imdb\parser\http\__init__.py", line 395, in _get_search_content
    cont = self._retrieve(self.urls['find'] % params)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.KRATER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\imdb\parser\http\__init__.py", line 378, in _retrieve
    ret = self.urlOpener.retrieve_unicode(url, size=size)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.KRATER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\imdb\parser\http\__init__.py", line 248, in retrieve_unicode
    raise IMDbDataAccessError(
imdb._exceptions.IMDbDataAccessError: {'errcode': None, 'errmsg': 'None', 'url': 'https://www.imdb.com/find?q=titanic&s=tt', 'proxy': '', 'exception type': 'IOError', 'original exception': URLError(ConnectionRefusedError(10061, 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it', None, 10061, None))}
```

I am unable to find an answer simple enough to implement, some say I need to update my environment variables. Can anyone walk me through it (very slowly), I recently started using python.

Also, I only have Windows Defender as antivirus, and the script was working when I last tried few weeks ago.

---

Here's the python code I'm using:

```
    from imdb import IMDb 
ia=IMDb()
#here we use a keyword, say 'matrix' to get a list of movies, from which we select the first movie, then get its' ID and extract details of it. 
 
movie = ia.search_movie('titanic')
print (movie[0])
id= movie[0].movieID

print(id)
movie2 = ia.get_movie(id)

print('/dir:')
for director in movie2['directors']:
    print(director['name'].join(" ,"),end='')

print()
print('/cast:')
for cast in movie2['cast']:
    print(cast['name'].join(" ,"),end='')

print()
print('/genre:')
for genre in movie2['genre']:
    print(genre.join(" ,"),end='')
    
print()
print('/runtime:')    
for runtime in movie2['runtime']:
    print(runtime)
    
#finish`
```

Comment: Kindly provide your code and write the error in a code box....

Comment: Yep, a [mcve] would be called for. Also, search for the error message online to get an idea of what causes it. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].